# JUnit Test at runtime

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, junit

I am trying to create Test cases during runtime.

Background:
I'm calling the test like this:

```
public class XQTest {


XQueryTest buildTest = new XQueryTest();

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    buildTest.test();
}
}
```

Afterwards it searches the FileDirectory for matching Files and build tests from it.

**XQueryTest.java**

```
 tester = new XQueryTester(a, b);
 tester.testHeader(c, d);
```

**XQueryTester.java** performs the actual assertion.

Is it possible to "outsource" these actual Testcases, so it's easier to Identify which test failed on jenkins, because at the moment I only have One Test (**XQTest.java**) which generate serveral tests.
Another problem is, if one test fails, the whole Test failed and skips the rest, even though it's just a part of the whole.

Comment: Why did you choose to create unit tests in such an unconventional fashion?

Comment: Because I have different modules which needs to be tested

Comment: I was asking why you've created your own complicated mechanism instead of using standard JUnit mechanisms. What do you mean by "different modules" and why wouldn't regular JUnit tests work with those?

Comment: What would've been simplier in your opinion?

Due to CI I'm creating a test engine which generates tests from resources (files...) so that the user doesn't need to write tests anymore.

I dont really get your point :/

Comment: Well that makes two of us. Users don't write tests, programmers or testers do. You already have a test engine, it's called JUnit. You don't need to write your own engine just because you're using CI, in fact as you've now noticed it causes problems. You shouldn't create tests at runtime, they should be created at compile-time already (and there are tools for generating them).

Comment: For example? :)

Comment: So you're capable of writing your own runtime test generator, but you can't find existing tools for helping in creating unit tests?

Comment: Actually I haven't finished it yet. :P

Without being rude, can't you just tell me, since I'm not really into JUnit

Comment: Well then drop what you're doing and learn it. You can't really expect to write an "addition" to JUnit without understanding how JUnit works. But hey, 1 second of Googling resulted in [JUnit 5 Generate tests at runtime](https://dzone.com/articles/junit-5-dynamic-tests-generate-tests-at-run-time), so looks like they beat you to it.

Comment: Thats exactly where i'm currently stuck, do you know how to convert a lambda expression to a function/method, since i'm using Java7?

`Executable exec = () -> assertEquals(outPhr, translatorEngine.tranlate(phr));`

Comment: Use an anonymous class (or it doesn't need to be anonymous, but that would be the direct equivalent). Although based on the text in that article you might have to do additional work as well to get pre-Java 8 code out of it.

Comment: So your suggestion is to upgrade to Java8?

Comment: Well if that's possible I'd definitely recommend it. Java 9 will be out soon, so unless you need to support legacy applications I don't see why you should stick with Java 7.

Comment: Is a Parameterized test maybe an alternative too?

Comment: Maybe, who knows. You should find out.

Answer (score 1):

[Junit5](https://junit.org/junit5/) supports a runtime tests via the TestFactory and DynamicTest concepts.

See

- https://dzone.com/articles/junit-5-dynamic-tests-generate-tests-at-run-time
- https://www.baeldung.com/junit5-dynamic-tests